# ExtJs remote (list) filter reset

Tags: extjs

I have an issue with Extjs remote filter that I excpect you could help to clarify.

I've created a grid with a remote filter that works great, but if I update the grid info, the filter keeps the previous loaded data.

I've tried everything: **store.doDestroy**, **store.removeAll**, even **assign a new store** to the var with Ex.create, but I didn't succeed.

I've created a [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2h9l&view/editor) to try to reproduce my issue:

1. First load default info (Simpsons)
2. Then open the 'Hobbie' filter (Simulates a select distinct). You get **Jazz, Skate, Beer and Knit**.
3. After that, update the grid data (Switch to Van Houtens)
4. Finally, try to get Van Houtens hobbies (**Videogames, Margaritas and None**), but you get Simpsons Hobbies (**Jazz, Skate..**), cause the filter was previously loaded. (Notice how there was not a loading mask).
5. Now restart the test skipping step 2 (and 5 to avoid infinite loop XD) and notice how the right hobbies are shown.

I need to 'reset' that previous store load.

Notes:

- If I just do a **store.load**, the request is triggered, but the returned values are not bound to the filter list.
- If try to bind the store with this **bind:{store:'{filterStore}'}**, noting happens

Comment: From the fiddle, I don't see wheere you are stuck.

Comment: It is still not at all clear what the problem is. What do you mean by 'try to get'?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. If you see [this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/1ZwvXy8.png), I don't see where you are trying to load only filters for one family. The "filters for simpson family" are the whole list of `hair.json`, that's why these are always shown. Please elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I made some updates to the [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2h9l&view/editor). Now the hair color filter should be based on the family filter. Notice how that filter is not cleared (or at least I don't know how) if the Grid content it's updated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to "rebind" the filters for each column like this:

```
var grid = this.up('grid');

//Clear the current filters before changing
grid.getPlugins()[0].clearFilters();

var store = grid.getStore();
setStoreFilter(store, 'Van Houten');

//Setting the store filters is not enough    
setStoreFilter(filterStore, 'Van Houten');
setStoreFilter(hobbiesStore, 'Van Houten');

//You need to "rebind" the store, it needs a little delay to work properly
setTimeout(function(){ grid.getColumns()[3].filter.bindMenuStore(hobbiesStore); }, 1000);
```

Here is the updated [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2hb5&view/editor)